# ANTLR4 parser not moving past first rule

Tags: antlr4

I am completely new to ANTLR and I am working on a programming language with my group at university for our semesterproject. We are using visitors for our parser but when I attempt to visit the tree, it doesn't move past the first rule and I have no idea why.

This is the code where I implement it:

```
public class Implementation {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SyntaxAnalysisLexer lexer = new SyntaxAnalysisLexer(CharStreams.fromFileName("<filepath>"));
        CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        SyntaxAnalysisParser parser = new SyntaxAnalysisParser(tokens);

        FuncCollect funcCollect = new FuncCollect();
        funcCollect.visit(parser.prog());

        EvalVisitor evalVisitor = new EvalVisitor(funcCollect.getEnvironment());
        evalVisitor.visit(parser.prog());

        List<String> errors = evalVisitor.getErrors();

        File file = new File("<filepath>");
        file.createNewFile();

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);

        for(String error : errors) {
            writer.append(error);
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a part of the grammar:

```
grammar SyntaxAnalysis;
//PARSER PART
prog:               (func | eventHand)* EOF                                     #program
                    ;

func:               'function' ftype ID '(' fparam ')' block 'endFunction'      #function
                    ;

eventHand:          'when' ID '(' fparam ')' block 'endWhen'                    #when
                    ;

block:              stmt*                                                       #blk
                    ;
```

And this is the two first visit functions:

```
@Override public SyntaxAnalysisType visitFunction(SyntaxAnalysisParser.FunctionContext ctx) {
    varEnv = new HashMap<>();
    visit(ctx.fparam());
    visit(ctx.block());

    return new SyntaxAnalysisVoid();
}

@Override public SyntaxAnalysisType visitWhen(SyntaxAnalysisParser.WhenContext ctx) {
    varEnv = new HashMap<>();
    visit(ctx.fparam());
    visit(ctx.block());

    return new SyntaxAnalysisVoid();
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what went wrong. I had to reset the parser before attempting to visit it a second time. So it went through it correctly the first time, but the second time it no longer knew where to go. I did this simply by writing this before the second visit:

```
parser.reset();
```

Comment: It's not necessary to parse the input twice. You can just visit the same tree twice if you store it in a variable instead of running the parser twice.